# What do I download to get a Apache 2.0.x + PHP 4.4.x environment?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend-framework

What do I download (on a windows box) to get a Apache 2.0.55 + PHP 4.4.7 environment?   I am fine with newer versions of PHP and Apache, but if I want to emulate a environment on an old SunOS server that has older versions of Apache and PHP.   Can anyone recommend the downloads i should use and where to get them?

Comment: I'm thinking I will try to use OpenSUSE 9.1 in a VirtualBox session and if that works, all is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you make it clear to whoever is running this software that they're an idiot, and they need to migrate off of it as quickly as possible.  You can cite lack of vendor support, known security flaws, and any number of other problems to convince them.

Then you download the appropriate Apache source tarball from [The Apache archive site](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/), and the old version of PHP from [their Release History page](http://www.php.net/releases/) and compile them yourself with the appropriate options.

Finally you plan, test, and ultimately execute a migration to software written *this century* :-)

Comment: Thanks, that PHP release history page is probably what I needed.

Comment: don't forget to get the compile options from `<?PHP phpinfo(); ?>` and `httpd -V` (Old 1.x apache the list of compiled-in modules (`httpd -l`) is probably useful too, and you'll need a 1.x mod_ssl if you want `https://` support)

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about the Apache version.  I fixed my question.  Thanks for the help. I'll close the question.